# useSWR to get get data of specific ID

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am using NextJS with SWR, and I want to fetch data with SWR for one specific ID.
When user click on Row of table, it will pull data with that ID from server.

Below is SWR code

```
export const apiExpenses = () => {

    const { data: showExpense, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/expenses/show', () =>
    axios
        .get('/api/expenses/show/' + expenseId)
        .then(res => res.data)
  )

  return {
    showExpense,
  }
};
```

Below code is for another component where `showExpense` is called,

```
const { showExpense } = apiExpenses();

const clickTo = async (expenseId) => {

    //How can i fetch data with specific ID in SWR?
    const expenseData = //Code?
  };

  //In JSX

  <IconButton onClick={() => clickTo(params.id)} color="primary">
```

I am not sure how can I pass `expenseId` to SWR API.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

First you need to pass `expenseId` to the hook:

```
export const apiExpenses = (expenseId) => {

    // You need to pass id to the swr hook, not to axios, otherwise it wont refetch data for another id
    const { data: showExpense, error, mutate } = useSWR(
      // Pass null when there is no id
      expenseId ? ('/api/expenses/show/' + expenseId) : null,
      (key) => axios.get(key).then(res => res.data)
  )

  return {
    showExpense,
  }
};
```

And on the other side you can just store current id in the state:

```
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState()
const { showExpense } = apiExpenses(currentId);

const clickTo = async (expenseId) => {
    setCurrentId(expenseId)
  };

  //In JSX

  <IconButton onClick={() => clickTo(params.id)} color="primary">
```